# Stop input showing in the url - Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am not sure what part of the code to include, will do my best to explain the code structure and post requested code.

This Meteor web app is one page dynamic template app. User enters data in `input` elements, then button event calls method which uses jQuery to loop over all input elements, building an array of objects, an object for each element {elementName: elementValue}, then sends that array to the backend server to save in Mongodb collection.
The template helper fetches the documents which is used as the data source for the template to populate those same input elements later if need be.

Often I see the data which were input by the user in the browser URL and need to stop that from happening, Any idea where and how to start to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting the form on click. So You have to prevent the form submission on click.
Like:

```
"submit #myform": function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: in addition You could `return false;` in that function